# jQuery alert doesnt work with jQuery event

Tags: jquery

```
    <script src="jQuery/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jQuery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jQuery/jquery-1.7.2-vsdoc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jQuery/jquery-ui-vsdoc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        $("div").mouseover(function() {
            alert("bla");
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>hello world !!!</div>
</body>
```

I want the user be able to click on Div and then a message box will appear.
y doesnt it work (both on Chrome and IE9) ? using WebMatrix 2.0 !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok solved the problem.. actually its quite stupid:

i just passed the VSDOC js in top of the regular js

```
<script src="jQuery/jquery-1.7.2-vsdoc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jQuery/jquery-ui-vsdoc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jQuery/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jQuery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

thank u all :)

Answer (score 0):

In the current version of your code when the code is executed the div DOM elements is not yet available in the DOM .

You need to wrap the handler in the document ready handler.
Try this:

```
$(function(){
   $("div").mouseover(function() {
       alert("bla");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @roko-c-buljan says you just can register events after DOM is ready

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $("div").mouseover(function() {
            alert("bla");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: change mouseover to mouseenter